# Can you reference an item in qt resource file in the qt project file?

Tags: windows, qt, icons

I have a resource file `App.qrc` and I want to set an windows icon to the program's executable (`.ico` not `QIcon`).

My question is, is it possible for you to use the `ico` file which is in `App.qrc` like this to set the `.exe` icon:

```
win32:RC_ICONS += :/Icon.ico
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Is it not possible because the qrc file is compiled so it's in the exercise file

Comment: It's not possible because the icon needs to be found by RC, the Windows tool that processes `.rc` files. That has nothing to do with Qt and knows nothing about Qt's resource system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to include the file path outside the Qt Resource System (you can include the same file in both `App.qrc` and in `RC_ICONS`).

```
win32:RC_ICONS += icon.ico
```

- [`RC_ICONS`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-icons) works by generating a [`.rc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file that includes the icons specified. That means the icons will be stored in the result `.exe` file using windows resource management (and only then `explorer.exe` will be able to recognize the icon of the `.exe` file).
- While, when you add the icon to `App.qrc`, it will be using [Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) to store the icon in the result `.exe`. This is Qt's platform-independent mechanism for storing binary files in the application's executable. This can't be read by `explorer.exe` (it can be read only  from Qt classes that depend on the [`QFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#details) class).

Clearly, these are two different system to get your icon (or other resource) stored within the result `.exe` file, and they use different ways to do that, so you can't specify an icon from the Qt Resource system to be included in the generated RC file.